# Get Google sheets column by name in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that allows me to get the contents of a column from my Google Sheet and display it in my HTML form while removing any duplicates of the same name.

Example: red, red, yellow, yellow, blue, green would show in the dropdown menu as red, yellow, blue, green.

The thing is, I would like to get the column contents by name and not by number i.e 1.

Here is my script:

```
function getColors() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1czFXXQAIbW9IlAPwHQ0D5S_a-Ew82p-obBEalJFNJTI").getSheetByName("Vinyl Costs");
  var getLastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue());
      }
  }


  return return_array;  
}
```

I've found a similar question and the accepted answer was this:

```
function getByName(colName, row) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var col = data[0].indexOf(colName);
  if (col != -1) {
    return data[row-1][col];
  }
}
```

But I can't seem to make that work with mine? This is my first ever Google Script so I don't really understand it 100% yet.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the functions a bit.
For one thing, `getByName` now gets not all values of the sheet, but only the first row.

```js
  function getColors() { 
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1czFXXQAIbW9IlAPwHQ0D5S_a-Ew82p-obBEalJFNJTI").getSheetByName("Vinyl Costs");

    const colName = 'your_column_name';
    const colNum = getColNumberByName(colName);
    if (colNum === null) {
      Logger.log('Column ' + colName + ' was not found!');
      return [];
    }

    const firstRow = 2;
    const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    // get all values from column
    const columnData = sheet.getRange(firstRow, colNum, lastRow).getValues().flat();

    // filter values on duplicates
    return columnData.filter((el, i) => i === columnData.indexOf(el) && el !== '');
  }

  function getColNumByName(colName, row = 1) {
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1czFXXQAIbW9IlAPwHQ0D5S_a-Ew82p-obBEalJFNJTI").getSheetByName("Vinyl Costs");
    
    const [data] = sheet.getRange(row, 1, row, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    const col = data.indexOf(colName);

    // adding 1 because column nums starting from 1
    return col === -1 ? null : col + 1;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code does actually work but it adds a blank under the last item allowing you to select a blank?